# Change the title of the dropdown header

Tags: react-native, drop-down-menu, categories, picker

I am using react-native-dropdown-picker v 4.0.2;

I am trying to change the title, here I found default value **select an item**, How can I change the default title, like **select a category**

here is an expo link
https://snack.expo.io/@mamun_121/testing_snack

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import SelectMultiple from 'react-native-select-multiple'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';


class Dropdown extends Component {
  
  state = {
    items: ['sports']
  }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <DropDownPicker
        items={[
          {label: 'Sports', value: 'sports', icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" />},
          {label: 'Books', value: 'book', icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" />},
        ]}

        placeholder="Select category"
        multiple={true}
        multipleText="%d categories have been selected."
        min={0}
        max={10}
        
        defaultValue={this.state.items}
        containerStyle={{height: 40}}
        itemStyle={{
          justifyContent: 'flex-start'
        }}
        onChangeItem={item => this.setState({
          items: item // an array of the selected items
        })}
      />
    )
  }
}
export default Dropdown;
```

[image: Dropdown]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the "placeholder" prop instead of the label.

```
 <DropDownPicker
        items={[
          {label: 'Sports', value: 'sports', icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" />},
          {label: 'Books', value: 'book', icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" />},
        ]}
        
        placeholder="Select category"
        multiple={true}
        multipleText="%d categories have been selected."
        min={0}
        max={10}
        defaultValue={'sports'}
        containerStyle={{height: 40}}
        itemStyle={{
          justifyContent: 'flex-start'
        }}
        onChangeItem={item => this.setState({
          items: item // an array of the selected items
        })}
      />
```

Working snack
https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/646ecd

Comment: Thanks Guruparan Giritharan